# Hive JDBC Mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

Generally, if I write a HQL query in Hive CLI, it executes as a map reduce job. If I have a select query in a Hive JDBC program, is it also a map reduce job? Does it also have all the advantages of a map reduce job?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. ultimately Hive JDBC query goes through Hive engine and it will use either map reduce or a simple java code.

For every hive cli or hive jdbc query at run time hive engine decides weather to use map reduce or simple java code.